# How to solve latch warning?

Tags: vhdl, warnings, fpga, xilinx

I have a question about VHDL. The following code is for a player turn selector in a game. It simulates well, but when I generate a bit stream it has a warning that says:
"[Synthesizer 8-327] infer latch for variable 'teToca_reg' [" C: /...../ Eleccion.vhd ": 137]"
The main problem is generated by an assignment made in a process, which I need in order for the "cambio" signal to receive the first value of the turn in that game, and to be able to change after each time B1 is pressed. The problem appears because the assignment is done later combinationally in the opposite direction so that the output "teToca" takes the changed value.
The signal "FinPartida" is set to 1 when a game ends and "win" gives a value, so "teToca" receives a new value.

```
proceso_switch: process(clk,reset)
    begin
        if reset = '1' then
            cambia <= '0';
        elsif clk'event and clk='1' then
            if FinPartida='1' then
                cambia <= tetoca; --LATCH
            elsif state = S_JUEGO and flanco='1' and B1='1' and posicion/=9 and pos1(posicion)='0' and pos2(posicion)='0' then
                cambia <= NOT cambia; --OK
            end if; 
        end if;
    end process;

teToca <=   empieza when state = S_ESPERA and reset = '0' else  
            '0' when state = S_ESPERA and reset = '1' else      
            --PLATCH--                                                                                                                
            cambia when state = S_JUEGO AND (flanco='1' and B1='1' and posicion/=9 and pos1(posicion)='0' and pos2(posicion)='0') else
            --LATCH--
            '0' when state = S_JUEGO AND win="001" else 
            '1' when state = S_JUEGO AND win="100";     

turno <= teToca;
```

Comment: teToca is a latch because there is no final else, so it cannot be a combinatorial value... cambia looks fine!

Comment: IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 RTL Synthesis (withdrawn) 6. Modeling hardware elements, 6.2 Level-sensitive sequential logic "A level-sensitive storage element shall be modeled for a signal (or variable) when all the following apply: a) The signal (or variable) has an explicit assignment. b) The signal (or variable) does not have an execution path with <clock_edge> as a condition. c) There are executions of the process that do not execute an explicit assignment (via an assignment statement) to the signal (or variable)."  The missing `else` meets c).

Comment: A conditional signal assignment statement which represents an equivalent if statement (IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.5.3 Conditional signal assignments)  is elaborated into an equivalent process (11.6 Concurrent signal assignment statement). The assignment to `teToca` appears to have  'executions of the process' meeting c) as well.

Comment: @ÁngelAlegreBurcio It needs to be a final else with no when clause, so that it has a branch to take when no other branch is specified.

Comment: I finally solved the problem, thank you all!